# Modeling Identifying states & Modeling Validation in State Machine Diagram

Tags: uml, state-machine

I am wondering what might I consider as States when I am asked to model state of a Booking Process (eg. Booking a Movie Ticket Online).

I did something like

[image]

It looks abit bloated mainly because of the validation. Should I even have a Validating XXX state? Or should it be something more like:

[image]

Comment: This is a activity diagram and each box needs to be an use case from the use case diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends if the validation processes are synchronous or asynchronous.

For synchronous validation, there is no need for the validation state. The validation result is given immediately, the system never remains in a validation phase.

For asynchronous validation, a validation state is required because the validation result event is not immediate but is received later on. Typically an asynchronous call such as "startValidation" is invoked upon entering the validation state, and transitions handle the events "validationSuccess" and "validationError"

Comment: How do you define synchonized/async validations? Can I say sync-ed is done by the system? While async will probably call another system/service to validate? Something like http://pastie.org/2625068

Comment: If so I will have http://i.imgur.com/N2LCE.png, since only payment verification is done by external system

Comment: Have a look at the [booking process state machine](http://www.stateforge.com/StateMachineDiagram/StateMachineDiagram.html?fsmUrl=/examples/dotnet/BookingProcess.fsmcs) created with my state machine editor. By the way, it uses a hierarchical state machine to handle the timer events.